# Suspend subscription for UI updates in the background and restart it on foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, rx-swift

I have many subscriptions that update the UI, but I'd like to suspend them when the app goes in the background because they are still firing and updating parts of my view controller.

What is the best way to handle this to be conscious of memory and unnecessary UI updates in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on what your app is doing in the background.

Maybe it's:

- Is it a `timer`/`interval` that keeps going.
- An `Observable` of a network request that hasn't returned yet or that's connected to a WebSocket.
- An `Observable` that's listening to system events like the screen orientation changing.

Depending on what `Observable`s you're concerned about, you might want to handle it differently.  For the case of a network request, you might want to cancel it, or possibly cancel it and then restart it upon foreground.  If it's a system event like orientation change, you might want to just get the current value upon foreground.

In any case, I'd have to ask, why are you so concerned with memory?  I'd say, let iOS handle system memory concerns.  If it decides to kill your app, your `Disposable`s should be cleaned up properly on their own (if you're correctly using `DisposeBag`s).  Then, you should only be concerned with your app maintaining enough state so that it can pick up where it left off (being on the right page, etc.).  I wouldn't recommend trying to over optimize on iOS's behalf.  Let your app keep running as long as iOS lets you.  Your user might just be jumping over to another app for just a second or something.

Comment: Problem is my Rx's are firing in the background and updating UI elements, and when coming to the foreground my app freezes because the UI is catching up to fulfill the requests from the Rx. So I'm thinking I should suspend the observers that are updating UI.

Comment: So then it becomes a question of what's an appropriate way to suspend the Observables in question. Ignore all events, buffer the last, etc. you could use a combination operator with a new background/foreground operator if you need.

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplicationDelegate` (i.e. your AppDelegate.swift) has some useful methods worth implementing that may get you close to what you're looking for

Try implementing these:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    // Do something to notify your services to unsubscribe
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {

   // Do something to resubscribe for notification and also catch up for anything you missed while in the background
}
```

It's probably worth reading up on `UIApplicationDelegate` some more and learning about all the possible states such as 'Active' and 'Inactive' too, but this should get you going in the right direction
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate